# Why does this anko layout not handle the system ui correctly?

Tags: android, xml, android-styles, anko

I'm trying out Anko and can't get this layout to handle system ui like the xml version. I figure it has something to do with Themes and how they're handled through xml parsing.

Here are screenshots:

[image: fim]
[image: sim]

Here's the anko DSL component:

```
class ActivityMainLayout : AnkoComponent<Activity> {

    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var appBarLayout: AppBarLayout
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    lateinit var text: TextView
    lateinit var navHeader: NavigationView
    lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<Activity>): View = with(ui) {
        drawerLayout = drawerLayout {

            fitsSystemWindows = true

            coordinatorLayout {

                appBarLayout = appBarLayout(theme = R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay) {

                    toolbar = toolbar {
                        popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme_PopupOverlay
                        backgroundColor = getColorPrimary(ui.owner)
                    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = getActionBarSize(ui.owner))

                }.lparams(width = matchParent)

                nestedScrollView {

                    text = textView {
                        text = "Anko Version"
                        textSize = 40f
                    }.lparams {
                        margin = dip(16)
                    }

                }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
                    behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
                }

            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

            navHeader = navigationView {
                inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_test_design)
                inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_test_design_drawer)
            }.lparams(height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.START
            }
        }

        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                ui.owner, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)

        return drawerLayout
    }

    fun getActionBarSize(ctx: Context): Int {
        val attrs = IntArray(1)
        attrs[0] = attr.actionBarSize
        val array = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
        val size = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0)
        array.recycle()
        return size
    }

    fun getColorPrimary(ctx: Context): Int {
        val attrs = IntArray(1)
        attrs[0] = attr.colorPrimary
        val array = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
        val color = array.getColor(0, 0)
        array.recycle()
        return color
    }
```

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:text="XML Version" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_test_design"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_test_design_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the problem by simply removing the **`fitsSystemWindows = true`** from the `drawerLayout { ... }` block.

I keep `fitsSystemWindows = true` inside both `coordinatorLayout { ... }` and `navigationView { ... }` blocks. With this change, the StatusBar is transparent and the correct padding space is reserved for it on top of the AppBar.

However, I found that another problem still remained: *the AppBar itself was scrollable* up and behind the Android StatusBar (?!), which is something that should never happen...

I have solved this other problem by adding **`behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()`** in the `lparams` block of the `appBarLayout { ... }` (the same may be applied for `themedAppBarLayout`), like this:

```
themedAppBarLayout(theme = R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay) {
    toolbar() {
        id = R.id.toolbar
        popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme_PopupOverlay
        backgroundResource = R.color.colorPrimary
    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = dimenAttr(R.attr.actionBarSize))
}.lparams(width = matchParent) {
    behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
}
```

This makes the AppBar fixed and not scrollable anymore (as it should be).

Both problems are probably related and also referenced in this issue of the Anko project on GitHub:
[NavigationDrawer makes status bar with white background · Issue #298 · Kotlin/anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/298)

This works with Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2, Kotlin 1.1.4-2 and Anko 0.10.1.